# What is a good stash?

Tags: nethack

I always tend to die before being too much encumbered or filling my BoH enough, but I wonder: **what is the ultimate stash configuration**?

I heard about boulder forts, but also blue jelly fort. I understand how to build a boulder fort (scroll of earth are good for that), but blue jelly fort... Do I need to reverse genocide them? Are the advantages of such a fort worth the spending of a scroll of genocide?

Comment: permanently engraved Elbereth usually makes for the best stash

Comment: That's a minimal Stash. I want the one with the options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are absolutely no advantages to anything beyond a container (which will prevent anything but a gel cube from affecting your stash at all in any way) and a permanent Elbereth (which will keep the gel cube off too.) Add a single boulder on top if you have any pets capable of lifting the container.

Reverse genociding blue jellies for the purpose is just silly.

Comment: As somebody who's only played enough Nethack to get myself in trouble - what's the talk about blue jellies, anyway?  What could you do with them?

Comment: Blue jellies are completely immobile, so they can be used to block off areas to prevent anything else from accessing them. It's also easy to create a lot of them because they split when they're attacked enough by non-cold-resistant attackers (when their passive attack damages you). This isn't particularly useful, although in one case a player filled Sokoban entirely with blue jellies to prevent anything else from spawning in order to overflow the turn counter and finish the game in a negative number of turns.

Comment: So they don't attack you? For that matter how would you get to the stash?

Comment: presumably by teleporting to it, although this is another reason not to try something like this for a stash.

Comment: how do you make an elbereth permanent?

Comment: @Bob: burn it into the ground with a wand of fire or a wand of lightning.

Comment: no other way? so if i just write it, how long will it last?

Comment: @Bob: depends on how much stuff you do while standing on it and how much monsters walk across it. This may make a good separate question; I couldn't find anything on here that explains erosion of engravings (although nethackwiki.com has a good treatment of it IIRC)